# Nokia Asha / J2me SSL Certification Error for Http request

Tags: java, ssl, java-me, nokia, nokia-s40

While we are trying to access API's through HTTP/HTTPS we are getting exception with the below message. But we are trying the same URL's in other platforms (LUMIA) we are getting proper response and not getting any errors. While we are searching we found this issue is related to SSL but we could not find any more details or solutions to resolve the same. Please help us to resolve this issue.

Please find the details below:

Tested platform/Device: 
    Nokia Asha Softwate Platform 1.0, 1.1/ Asha 501

```
**Exception arised while try:**
java.io.IOException: Alert (2,40)type:22
at com.sun.midp.ssl.RecordReader.rdRec(), bci=224
at com.sun.midp.ssl.Handshake.getNextMsg(), bci=10
at com.sun.midp.ssl.Handshake.rcvSrvrHello(), bci=2
at com.sun.midp.ssl.Handshake.doHandShake(), bci=25
at com.sun.midp.ssl.SSLStreamConnection.<init>(), bci=163
at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.https.Protocol.connect(), bci=245
at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.streamConnect(), bci=48
at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.startRequest(), bci=7
at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.sendRequest(), bci=41
at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.sendRequest(), bci=3
at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.getResponseCode(), bci=5
```

- com.ascenso.jumia.network.HttpClient.sendRequest(HttpClient.java:157)
 - com.ascenso.jumia.network.HttpClient.run(HttpClient.java:415)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:723)

Comment: you seem to have a double exception: the first exception wants to display an alert. but the alert is throw another exception, maybe because it is not called in the UI-Thread. then you should catch the first exception and write log to get more information what exactly happened.